# .net Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im working on a website built in .net and im having some trouble with a 'validation'

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="<p>Invalid Phone Number!</p>"........
```

What this does is posts a message on the page with an inline style, what I need it to do is add a class to an input field instead, is this possible?

Comment: You might want to use javascript. It gives you so much more flexibilty for making this sort of thing work how you want it to. asp.net is OK for throwing something together quickly, but no good if you have more specific requirements.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add a class to an input field"?

Comment: @Ramhound I believe he means add a css class to the input field - eg something to highlight the field which has failed validation...

Comment: Id like to add a class to an input field if it doesnt pass validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a `CustomValidator` for this instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(v=VS.100).aspx

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ControlToValidate="Text1"
       ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
       ErrorMessage="<p>Invalid Phone Number!</p>"
       runat="server"/>


<script language="javascript">
   function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
   {
      var regexValid = false; // perform regular expression validation here manually
      if (regexValid) {
         arguments.IsValid=true;
      }
      else {
         // add the class to the desired input field
         arguments.IsValid=false;
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to look at a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead and write your regex validation and desired failure action in your own client-side script.

Answer (score 1):

This might work.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="<p>Invalid Phone Number!</p>"........

<cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender HighlightCssClass="your_css_class" runat="server" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator2" Enabled="true"/>
```